# I don't understand why its returning an empty console log

Tags: javascript, event-handling

```
document.body.append(document.createElement('textarea'));
document.body.append(document.createElement('button'));

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const text = document.querySelector('textarea').textContent;
  const lowerCase = text.toString().toLowerCase();
  console.log(lowerCase);
});
```

I am sorry if I don't display stuff properly here, I'm new to this place, and fairly new to coding but trying to figure out stuff.

Comment: `textContent` isn't reflected from the `value` property. Read `value` instead of `textContent`.

Comment: Thank you! my brain only figured it out a second ago too <3

Comment: Though textareas are a little counterintuitive in this regard as they don't support the `value` attribute in declaring the initial HTML.